# Install mac : 1 error generated (error: '_GStaticAssertCompileTimeAssertion_0' declared as an array)

Tags: python, macos, installation, kivy

I'm trying to install kivy on mac OSX 10.11.2 for a couple of hours now.
What I did (as explained here: https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-osx.html):

```
$ brew install sdl2 sdl2_image sdl2_ttf sdl2_mixer gstreamer
$ pip install -I Cython==0.23
$ USE_OSX_FRAMEWORKS=0 pip install kivy
```

The first two commands worked perfectly fine.
The last command give me this error:

```
16 warnings and 1 error generated.
 error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
```

When I look above the only error I get is:

```
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.48.2/include/glib-2.0/glib/galloca.h:32:
    /usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.48.2/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:422:3: error: '_GStaticAssertCompileTimeAssertion_0' declared as an array with a negative size
      G_STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof (unsigned long long) == sizeof (guint64));
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.48.2/include/glib-2.0/glib/gmacros.h:232:103: note: expanded from macro 'G_STATIC_ASSERT'
    #define G_STATIC_ASSERT(expr) typedef char G_PASTE (_GStaticAssertCompileTimeAssertion_, __COUNTER__)[(expr) ? 1 : -1] G_GNUC_UNUSED                                                                                                                                                                                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Could you help me? Let me know if you need more info.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem trying to install with CLI. It appears kivy installation with .app file worked. Follow this guide:

- https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-osx.html

then you should be able to import kivy. But I am sorry I can't help you more with this issue ^^